# Why does CGI.pm still use "\0" as null character, when it's treated as a normal character in Perl?

Tags: perl

Quoted from [in the CGI.pm docs](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.43/CGI.pm):

> When using this, the thing you must watch out for are multivalued CGI
>   parameters. Because a hash cannot distinguish between scalar and list
>   context, multivalued parameters will be returned as a packed string,
>   separated by the "\0" (null) character.

However, as it turns out, `\0` is nothing special in Perl:

```
print length("test\0hi");
```

The output is :

```
7
```

whereas in C it should be `4`.

Why does CGI.pm still use `\0` as null character, when it's treated as a normal character (not the mark of end of string any more) in Perl?

Comment: CGI.pm doesn't use it as a null character. It uses it as a separator because it's unlikely to be in the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a design mistake. I think we agree that it should not coerce the hash value to a string at all, but it probably seemed like a good idea back then and `\0` simply is the least bad choice for various reasons of little importance.

*Edit*: People usually avoid to put NULs in their data precisely because it tends to cause breakage in C programs, so this makes this character slightly more favourable as separator.

*Edit 2*: [hobbs comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7318929#comment-8831761) that it goes back to Perl 4, so the mistake is not in the original design, but in carrying it over and then not trying hard enough to deprecate the feature.

Well, hindsight is always perfect. [Hash::MultiValue](http://p3rl.org/Hash::MultiValue) is the smarter data structure you were thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

It's a security feature.

Users of `->Vars` expect a hash of key-values, where the values are strings. If one of the value happens to be a reference to an array, it would break that expectation and it could cause the program to behave badly.

If you want to support arguments with multiple values, use `->param` in list context. You can use it to build your own hash, if you want.

```
my %hash;
for ($cgi->params) {
   $hash{$_} = [ $cgi->param($_) ];
}
```

I strongly disagree about it being a design error. I think it's very very smart way of handling bad data (multiple instances of a parameter where at most one is expected).

Comment: You are correct. It's a security design and not a design _mistake_. Nulls are rarely (if ever) correct data, and returning a scalar string is the safest way to retrieve data.

Comment: "Users of `vars` expect a hash of key-values where the values are strings" because their minds have been warped by CGI.pm's shoddy interface for too many years, and the reason CGI.pm does it that way is emphatically *not* for security, but because it's aping `cgi-lib.pl`'s interrface from perl4, where references were unavailable. And no, "nulls are rarely correct" is not **nearly** good enough. `%00` is perfectly valid input, and percent-decoding happens before null-joining. This behavior is more likely to be the **cause** of security holes than the prevention of them.

Comment: @hobbs,it seems `%00` has no chance to get to CGI ,as all occurences of \ in the form is escaped into \\,and furthermore it's `urlencoded` after this. Say you need to input `\0` to generate `%00`,but `\0` is escaped into `\\0`

Comment: @new_perl, we're not talking about «`\ `»+«`0`», we're talking about U+0000, the character produced by the string literal `"\0"`, and it can indeed appear in URL-encoded strings. For example, here's such a URL: `http://example.com/?foo=%00`

Comment: But the multivalued case only happens when submitting a form, so it's still fine.(Unless the hacker posts the form using a program:) But he can benifit nothing IMO.)